# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'samples'

Tags: python, opencv, github

After cloning the GitHub repo of OpenCV, I am trying to run grabcut.py but I am getting error : 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "grabcut.py", line 114, in  
    img = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile(filename)) 
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'samples'

Here is the link to the file:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/grabcut.py

Comment: `cv2.samples.findFile` is used to find filepath.  At least in `OpenCV 4.0.1 (python)`, there is no `cv2.samples` submodule. You can just write a `findFile` to generate absolute path, such as `os.path.join("/ABSOLUTE_OPENCV/samples/data/", filename)` . Notice, you can download `samples/data` from [github/opencv](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`samples` submodule is available in `opencv-python version 4.0.0.21`. Use pip install to install that specific version, or a later version that has this submodule.

```
pip install opencv-python==4.0.0.21
```

Comment: Didn't work for me on Windows, still the same error.  Not did installing the latest version (4.1.1) work.

Comment: That helped me , Only after a restart

Comment: @yunus Please do consider upvoting the answer, if it helped you. :)

Comment: that *specific* version isn't required, but any version since the introduction of that feature. documentation says that it has existed since at least 4.0.0 and 3.4.4

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
img = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile(fileName))
```

To

```
img = cv.imread(fileName)
```

as there is no cv.samples module

Comment: interesting. according to official documentation still exist, I think need to update: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/deb/tutorial_display_image.html