# open cv attribute error no attribute samples

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to learn opencv and when I try to execute the code it gives me the error
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'samples'
the line in question is img = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile("road.png"))
im on ubuntu 18.04 what can be done?
the entire code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import sys
img = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile("starry_night.jpg"))
if img is None:
    sys.exit("Could not read the image.")
cv.imshow("Display window", img)
k = cv.waitKey(0)
if k == ord("s"):
    cv.imwrite("starry_night.png", img)
```

Comment: Could you post the whole code?, with just one line it's difficult to know what are you doing

Comment: This perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54972811/attributeerror-module-cv2-cv2-has-no-attribute-samples

Comment: Why not just [download](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/data/starry_night.jpg) the needed image from the github repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an outdated version of OpenCV.

the `cv::samples` namespace and its functions have been available at least since versions 4.0.0 or 3.4.4, according to documentation.

you should use a newer version of OpenCV. the `opencv-python` module on the PyPI (installable with `pip`) is very well maintained.